# DNS problems after upgrading from 16.04 to 17.10: How to reset the DNS settings to default?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, dns, 17.10

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10, the DNS settings doesn't seem to work anymore. I guess that this might have to do something with the migration from `resolvconf` to `systemd-resolv`.

How can I make sure that the installed packages and configurations are in default state as intended for 17.10?

For example, I noticed that `resolvconf` is installed and I removed it. However, this didn't solve the problem. I am guessing that there are more steps to make sure that it's on 17.10 default settings.

I can make it work (temporarily) by explicitly setting a nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` (for example `nameserver 8.8.8.8`), but this isn't the intended way to do it.

Comment: what about using google dns or opendns?

Comment: The 8.8.8.8 is the google dns. I tried it as suggested by spark, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This post seems more complete (both the question and answer): https://askubuntu.com/questions/966870/dns-not-working-after-upgrade-17-04-to-17-10

Comment: My 3 least favorite things about ubuntu have all collided -- networkmanager, systemd, and resolv.conf.  Yippee...

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problems. My DNS stopped working after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10.

1. The solution that temporarily worked was putting into `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

   ```
   DNS=<DNS server here>
   FallbackDNS=<DNS server here>
   ```

   and then restarting `systemd-resolved` by running

   ```
   #sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
   ```
2. The other way is to change in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

   ```
   dns=dnsmasq
   ```

   to

   ```
   dns=systemd-resolved
   ```

   Then restart NetworkManager by running:

   ```
   #sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
   ```

and your DNS should work.

Comment: Thanks, however both methods don't work for me (even after reboot).

Answer (score 2):

I found [an excellent blog post](https://www.hecticgeek.com/2017/04/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-dns-issues/) about the latest Ubuntu's DNS problem with `systemd-resolved` that solved the issue for me.

The steps are :

1. add a line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf`
2. install unbound with `sudo apt-get install unbound`
3. disable the troublesome daemon with:

   `sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved`

   `sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved`
4. add `dns=unbound` in the [main] section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
5. enable `unbound` with:

   `sudo systemctl enable unbound-resolvconf`

   `sudo systemctl enable unbound`
6. Reboot the computer

Comment: But how can you download anything when there is no DBS

Comment: That's the purpose of step 1. It sets up the DNS of Google (8.8.8.8). The problem I had was that the file was overwritten on system boot.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question.  I switched to unbound just after asking this question. The point of this quesiton is of how I reset all DNS related settings to factory default (in particular using systemd-resolved).

Answer (score 2):

As @spark said, you must edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and after restarting the service, all thing work but you don't see any change in `/etc/resolv.conf` because **systemd-resolved** works differently from **resolveconf** service.

**systemd-resolved** use an intermediate resolver (`127.0.0.53`) to pass all requests to DNS servers that you specify in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` **DNS** section. so you shouldn't change `/etc/resolv.conf` directly. if you want to check if your changes are affected, you can open `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` to see your DNS servers. this is the file that **systemd-resolved** uses to resolve addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the DNS problem I tried the four "fixes" noted above and none worked. I had lost my eth0 connection when my upgrade crashed with some missing files. I needed to get an Internet connection before I could do anything to fix problem so I tried this using ideas from your Solution 4:

1. Edit the `resolve.conf` file by adding line nameserver 8.8.8.8
2. install unbound with `sudo apt-get install unbound`

After running 2 above I observed HAD AN INTERNET CONNECTION!
Next, I did the following:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

This reloaded the entire UBUNTU 17.10. Then I ran `sudo install -f` to fix any broken packages. The final result was a working system on my 12-year-old Althon 3500 64-bit machine. ABIT NF-91 mainboard, 2GB ram.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:
Checking Default route
Use one of these commands:

```
route -n
```

or

```
ip r
```

Ask a new IP address and amend the connection with the next command:

```
dhclient -v wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10 although for me `systemd-resolved` was fine.

The problem for me was in`/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

After commenting out the `hosts: files` entries DNS worked again.