# DNS not working after upgrade 17.04 to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I've just upgraded my laptop from Xubuntu 17.04 to 17.10.
After the final reboot, DNS has stopped working. This is obviously a problem! I can ping known IP addresses; just no DNS resolution.

I've not fiddled with any DNS settings; as far as I know, I had the standard DNS configuration previously. Its just a laptop which uses DHCP to get details from my home WiFi router.

Obviously, the ability to diagnose this is limited when the system itself can't resolve any web addresses. I did some googling on my phone, and most of the answers I found seemed to recommend turning dnsmasq off. However, dnsmasq was already off. But `/etc/resolv.conf` was showing 127.0.1.1, which seems to imply that it was expecting dnsmasq to be running.

I turned dnsmasq ON, by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` 
and adding

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

and then I ran this command

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

My DNS resolution is now working.

However, given that the default Ubuntu configuration is *not* to use dnsmasq, what should I actually have done to diagnose and fix this instead?

Answer (score 35):

I was updating Ubuntu today form version 16.10 through 17.04 to 17.10. For me too DNS stopped working. The `resolv.conf` symlink was

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
```

This is apparently wrong for 17.10.
The error message the previous poster got is from the output of `resolvconf -service`:

```
$ systemctl status resolvconf
```

It gave the following output.

```
resolvconf[623]: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

By removing the original symlink, linking to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` to `/etc/resolv.conf` and restarting the resolvconf -service DNS began working again:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
$ systemctl restart resolvconf
```

Interestingly the exit code of the `resolvconf-service` was success even before the symlink was pointing towards the correct file.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly my issue. So... how does one alert Canonical about this?

Comment: You should probably file a bug report so this behavior on upgrade is fixed.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, I had the same problem after installing ubuntu 17.10 from the website ~ 1 week ago. Thanks for sharing

Comment: fixed my problem when switching from 17.04 to 17.10. issues with openvpn dns as well.

Comment: This did nothing for `Temporary failure in name resolution` after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04.

Answer (score 7):

I found this bug reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/1725840; please confirm that you also suffering from it. It is resolved through a simple `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and saw this looking at resolvconf

```
Oct 20 00:36:17 drew-8570w resolvconf[708]: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Recreating the symlink fixed it. Now using 127.0.0.53 by default now?

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root drew 27 Apr  6  2017 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Comment: Where did you saw the warning? What command should I run?

Comment: Thank you, but this hasn't fixed the DNS problem for me. I tried the new symlink, but not working. I reverted back to the old symlink, also with dnsmasq in the config file, and this still works. As I asked earlier, does anyone know how I should _diagnose_ this?