# Upgrade to 17.10, now no network: Cable or Wireless

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, 17.10, realtek-wireless

I recently upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10. Now, I have no network whatsoever. Connected directly with a cable, or through wireless, all Ubuntu shows for my network is a question mark. My network was working just fine under 17.04. I'm not sure what happened here... But, this seems to be a bit of a perennial problem--at least for wireless. It happens pretty much every time I upgrade Ubuntu. I actually plan on going online to find out how I can get my wireless working again after an upgrade. However, this time, I have no network---at all.

I've got a Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi Adapter, if that's helpful.

This is a dual-boot machine with Win 10 also installed. Networking is fine on the Win 10 box. Any thoughts..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably seeing the same problem that has been answered here [DNS not working after upgrade 17.04 to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966870/dns-not-working-after-upgrade-17-04-to-17-10/967341#967341)

Your /etc/resolv.conf is pointing to networkmanagers resolv.conf, it should point to

```
 /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Restart after fixing the symlink, restart resolvconf and you network should work again.

Comment: Do you mean restart resolvconf, or do a full reboot? How do you restart resolvconf, or the network service/daemon, instead of a full reboot? Apparently updating the kernel doesn't even need a reboot anymore