# No internet after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10

I upgraded my laptop to new Ubuntu distribution 17.10 this afternoon/evening and since then I cannot connect to the internet.

I have tried both wired and wireless connections, but the icon in the status bar shows a question mark over the connection icon whichever method I've tried. I originally thought it was a wireless problem (it's a Realtek RTL8833EE card) so tried to connect via Ethernet to download the latest driver but find I can't connect with wire either.

I had a similar problem last week with 17.04 which I resolved somehow but I can't find exactly what I did.

Please can I have some suggestions as to what I should try to troubleshoot.

EDIT: I have tried the question (and the answer) here:

[DNS not working after upgrade 17.04 to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966870/dns-not-working-after-upgrade-17-04-to-17-10/967341)

both by adding a line

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

under /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, and by checking the resolvconf.service via

```
$ systemctl status resolvconf
```

which is NOT showing an error like

```
resolvconf[623]: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

I have confirmed that /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

Comment: This issue happened to me after some time on a 17.10 fresh install.
I only added "dns=dnsmasq" section and it solved it.
Resolvconf is not even installed, and it would have been complicated to install it without dns resolution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer I used in 17.04:

[How to disable systemd-resolved in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu)

It was systemd-resolved causing the DNS resolution problem. Following the instructions there to disable the service (and direct NetworkManager to use a different resolution service) has brought everything back up again.

Comment: to test this, you can temporarily edit /etc/resolv.conf and writer the ip address of your router in.