# Ubuntu upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 and now I have no internet unless I add a nameserver

Tags: networking, 17.10

I recently upgraded Ubuntu, and now whenever I restart my computer I have no internet. To get internet I have to edit my `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

It shows this when I load the file.

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

To get internet I have to add another nameserver, so I chose Google's, and now it looks like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

How to I get it so that I have internet when I restart?

Comment: Did you see this [Q&A: resolv.conf keeps getting reset by something](https://askubuntu.com/q/58781/522934)?

Comment: I just changed the `/etc/resolv.conf` just to get internet. I would like to know what changed as to why I don't have internet. I didn't have to do anything before the upgrade. It just worked.

Comment: Upgraded from what to what? Set a sms server in mn as a work around.

Comment: I upgraded from `17.04` to `17.10`.

Comment: And maybe have a look at this question: [No internet after upgrade to 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/967767/522934)