# 17.10: Find which script is putting "search somedomain.edu" in resolv.conf on startup

Tags: startup, systemd, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

The following files contain a line "search somedomain.edu", which prevents me from accessing that domain (DNS error in a browser).

- /run/resolvconf/interface/systemd-resolved
- /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
- /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
- /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

If a edit these files manually to remove the line "search somdomain.edu", then it repairs the DNS temporarily, I can access the domain in a browser. After startup, these files are automatically updated and the line "search somdomain.edu" came back, which prevents me from accessing the domain again...

**What I have tried**.
Editing the above files by hand does not work. I also looked for other files using

```
grep somedomain -r /run
```

and the same for /etc, /opt/, /usr.

**Questions**:

1. How to I prevent these files from being updated?
2. How to find the script that edits these files?\

**More info**: This problem appeared after I installed a proprietary debian package novell-iprint (which sets up printers at my institution). It did not work well, and I uninstalled the package. It seems that this package added a startup script that messes up the DNS. My diagnosis is that the removal of the package did not remove that startup script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `systemd-resolve` is in charge of updating these lines from the answer it gets from DHCP.

The issue you encounter is that for hosts in the domains listed in the `search` directive, it will fail if the system is badly configured.

In my case, I was not able to pin-point the exact reason for failure, but a `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` as suggested by https://askubuntu.com/a/972781 solved the issue for me.

Note that in my case, the `/etc/resolv.conf` link was left unchanged by reconfiguration, but something else must have changed and has solved the problem for me.