# WiFi connects but I can't browse

Tags: wireless, internet

Recently I came using Ubuntu on my Notebook normally, and out of nowhere I could not access anything else in Firefox, nor check for updates. Could someone help me?
I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on a Dell Inspiron 5558!
[Screenshot from the WiFi icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaCci.png)

BTW, there is the output of ip link and ip route:

```
gabriel@INSPIRON-5558:~$ ip link 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
2: enp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 
link/ether 84:7b:eb:e4:04:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000 
link/ether 68:14:01:a7:3c:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
4: anbox0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 
link/ether 16:a0:65:63:c3:de brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
gabriel@INSPIRON-5558:~$ ip route 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp6s0 proto static metric 20600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev anbox0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 
192.168.1.5 metric 600 192.168.250.0/24 dev anbox0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.250.1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your quesiton and include the output of `ip link`  and `ip route` when connected to a WiFi. You can run the commands from a terminal.

Comment: @vidarlo I already added to the question.

Comment: Shows that the connection is up. What happens if you try respectively `ping -c 4 google.com` and `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`? Does one of the ping commands work?

Comment: @vidarlo It shows that google.com is an unknown name or service, and 8.8.8.8 shows 4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms rtt min/AVG/max/mdex = 129.918/130.564/132.226/0.996 ms

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966870/dns-not-working-after-upgrade-17-04-to-17-10) Q&A. It's a DNS problem. I don't know the details of how 17.10 does DNS, but that Q&A should help you I believe. Try for instance `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` first.

Comment: @vidarlo I tried this instance and didn't worked, it shows a error of conflicting actions. I'll take a look on this other Q&A. BTW, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the error, was basically install resolvconf again and restart the computer. That means this problem has been solved!

How I did this:

1. Downloaded the .deb file of resolvconf. Link: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.79ubuntu8_all.deb
2. Installed the .deb file of resolvconf on terminal. Command: `dpkg -i <file location>`
3. Started resolvconf with systemctl. Command: `systemctl start resolvconf`
4. Rebooted the computer.
5. WiFi is back!

Comment: Snyver, you can accept your very own answer as well to mark the issue as solved (instead of adding `(SOLVED)` to the question's title).  But I'm not sure whether that works with your current reputation. But in general it works and is not considered a bad idea.

Comment: @PerlDuck OK, I'll remove it.