# Wifi in Ubuntu 17.10 is not sensing nearby networks

Tags: wireless, 17.10, resolvconf

When I typed `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` this was the error.

```
dpkg-query: package `resolvconf' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/bin/dpkg-reconfigure: resolvconf is not installed
```

Comment: Your question and the contents within are completely different questions.  What's your actual issue?  Wifi, or `resolvconf` being missing?

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install resolvconf  
sudo systemctl restart resolvconf  
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf  
sudo lshw -C network # shows wireless adapter information
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966870/dns-not-working-after-upgrade-17-04-to-17-10/967341#967341