# Install Ubuntu 17.10 Wireless issue

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, 17.10

after installing Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop, installed my VPN, for some reason I cannot connect to the internet. My wireless icon shows a "?". But here is the funny thing, if I login to my VPN, it works!

I've been around this forum, some others also. Tried a few things... nothing seems to work for me. I suspect from looking at other posts on forums its related to DNS and my VPN messed up my DNS settings.

I should also mention I'm kind of a Linux noob...

Any help is appreciated.

Joe

Here is one link I tried... [DNS problems after upgrading from 16.04 to 17.10: How to reset the DNS settings to default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965527/dns-problems-after-upgrading-from-16-04-to-17-10-how-to-reset-the-dns-settings).

I should also mention, the laptop is an old MBP (yeah I know, not meant for Ubuntu but its dead for all other OS's)

adding link to network info - http://paste.ubuntu.com/25942097/

Comment: Here it is (while on VPN as it is the only way i can connect) http://paste.ubuntu.com/25942097/

Comment: Could you please also include the content of the VPN network connection configuration file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`? Obviously you should redact any private information (passwords, user names, host names, public IP addresses). Thanks.

Comment: here is what I see in system connections. Also in folder VPN.

Comment: joe@Joe:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections$ ls -ls
total 12
4 -rw------- 1 root root 333 Nov  9 21:41 Apple
4 -rw------- 1 root root 393 Oct 31 14:03 ***** 2.4Ghz
4 -rw------- 1 root root 394 Nov  9 21:40 ****'"'"'s 5Ghz

Comment: total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 511 Oct  1 07:48 nm-openvpn-service.name
joe@Joe:/etc/NetworkManager/VPN$

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.